# SQL Loop Through Years but by Fiscal Year, Not Calendar Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a SQL Function that calculates the total number of hours a person has worked based on their start and end dates.

For example:

Start Date -------  End Date --------- Hours

3/1/2015 -------- 3/31/2015 --------- 100

4/1/2015 -------- 4/30/2015 --------- 100

5/1/2015 -------- 5/31/2015 --------- 130

...

The problem is that I can't do this by a calendar start and end date. (ie January to December ) It needs to be by Fiscal Start and End Date.

This needs to go from the person's start date (3/1/2015) to 12 months following that date (3/1/2016).

```
SELECT  year(StartDate), SUM(Hours)
from EmployeeHours 
WHERE EmployeeID = 12345
group by year(StartDate)
order by year(StartDate) desc
```

So this code returns the sums per year correctly, but it's based on calendar year.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example of your data tables?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, if that helps. I don't really have any data tables. It's all test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create a fiscal year which is either the current year, or the year +1 depending on what month you are in.

```
declare @EmployeeHours table (EmployeeId int not null, startdate date not null, enddate date not null, [hours] int not null)
insert into @EmployeeHours (EmployeeId, startdate, enddate, [hours]) values
  (12345, '2015-2-1', '2015-2-28', 100)
, (12345, '2015-3-1', '2015-3-31', 100)
, (12345, '2015-4-1', '2015-4-30', 100)
, (12345, '2015-5-1', '2015-5-31', 130)


SELECT datepart(year, startdate) + iif(DATEPART(MONTH, StartDate) > 2, 1,0) as [fiscalyear], SUM([Hours])
from @EmployeeHours 
WHERE EmployeeID = 12345
group by datepart(year, startdate) + iif(DATEPART(MONTH, StartDate) > 2, 1,0)
order by 1 desc
```

Output

```
2016   330
2015   100
```

Comment: I have a question. Let's add the following dates to this person:
"2016-01-01", "2016-01-31" 
"2016-02-01, "2016-02-28" 
"2016-03-01", "2016-03-30" 

How does your query know to grab the date from "2015-02-01" to "2016-02-01". So basically how does it know to grab all hours in that 12 month range? And NOT grab "2015-03-01"?

Comment: @AppDude27 - Your original question stated the fiscal year started in March (month 3). Also you can copy my query to your SSMS and you can add any dates and hours you want and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
create table #temp(StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime, Hours int)
insert into #temp values
 ('3/1/2015','3/31/2015' , 100) 
 ,('4/1/2015','4/30/2015' , 100 )
 ,('5/1/2015','5/31/2015', 130 )


Declare @sDate dateTime='2015-03-01'
Declare @EDate dateTime='2016-03-01'

SELECT  year(StartDate), SUM(Hours)
from #temp
WHERE 
--EmployeeID = 12345
--and 
StartDate>=@sDate and EndDate<=@EDate
group by year(StartDate)
order by year(StartDate) desc


 drop table #temp
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I made a modification to your query by changing @sDate to MIN(StartDate) and eDate to MAX(StartDate) so that we grab the full fiscal range.